# Why does a string converted from an array behave differently from another initialized with the same value?

Tags: python, string, decoding, string-conversion

The goal of the program is converting the little_endian string to another string equal to clean_data_little_endian and then to convert it using struct.unpack. However the string clean_data_little_endian behaves differently from the other, that is the result of a conversion from an array.

During debug clean_data_little_endian is à1ÿÏÿÊÿÄ and strBinary_Values is \xE0\x31\xFF\xCF\xFF\xCA\xFF\xC4 and if I try to print them I obtain
:

> clean_data_little_endian:  b'\xe01\xff\xcf\xff\xca\xff\xc4' <class 'str'>
>
> strBinary_Values:  b'\\xE0\\x31\\xFF\\xCF\\xFF\\xCA\\xFF\\xC4' <class 'str'>

(strBinary values has 2 backslashes instead of one)

There must be a difference that I don't know how to remove between them, so that struct.unpack works only with clean_data_little_endian and not with strBinary_Values.

The error returned is:

> unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes

and if I change the buffer the number of bytes required becomes the double and so on.

Here's the code I used, even if I think it will not be necessary to read it.

```
little_endian = '#800000100?xE0??x31??xFF??xCF??xFF??xCA??xFF??xC4?'
clean_data_little_endian = '\xE0\x31\xFF\xCF\xFF\xCA\xFF\xC4'

#from raw string to clean string
j=0
i=0
listValuesToClean = list(little_endian[10:len(little_endian)])
for i in range(0,len(listValuesToClean)-1):
    mod = i % 5
    if ((mod == 2) or (mod == 3) or (mod == 1)):
        listBinary_Values.append(listValuesToClean[i]) 
        j=j+1
    if (mod == 0):
        listBinary_Values.append('\\')
        j=j+1

strBinary_Values=''.join(listBinary_Values)
print('expected: ',clean_data_little_endian.encode('raw_unicode_escape'),type(strBinary_Values), '\n' 'real: ', strBinary_Values.encode('raw_unicode_escape'),type(clean_data_little_endian))
    
#from clean string to initial values
iqty_of_values = len(strBinary_Values)/8
h = "H" * int(iqty_of_values)

#correct result:
ivalues = struct.unpack("<"+h,clean_data_little_endian.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))

#wrong result:
ivalues = struct.unpack("<"+h,strBinary_Values.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))
```

Comment: The type of `b'\xe01\xff\xcf\xff\xca\xff\xc4'` is `str` only in  Python 2, which is obsolete. In Python 3 it is type `bytes`.  As a beginner you should not be investing time in learning Python 2, *particularly if this is the sort of problem you are interested in*. Those of us who still program in Python 2 do so only because we have to support or migrate legacy code.

Comment: @BoarGules looking at the print call in the question, the OP is printing the encoded value but calling type on the unencoded string.

Answer (score 1):

The double backslashes indicate a literal backslash, and it doesn't create the byte values you want.  This would fix it.  `latin1` translates 1:1 Unicode string codepoints to byte values, which is required for `unicode_escape` to translate the literal escape codes to Unicode string codepoints, but then encoding to `latin1` again turns the string back to the bytes required for `unpack`:

```py
ivalues = struct.unpack("<"+h,strBinary_Values.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1'))
print(ivalues)
# (12768, 53247, 51967, 50431)
```

From the looks of it, a regular expression to capture the hexadecimal bytes and a direct conversion using `bytes.fromhex` would be more straightforward:

```py
import re
import struct

little_endian = '#800000100?xE0??x31??xFF??xCF??xFF??xCA??xFF??xC4?'
s = ''.join(re.findall(r'x([0-9A-F]{2})',little_endian))
print(s)
b = bytes.fromhex(s)
print(b)
data = struct.unpack(f'<{len(b)//2}H',b)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
E031FFCFFFCAFFC4
b'\xe01\xff\xcf\xff\xca\xff\xc4'
(12768, 53247, 51967, 50431)
```